# Where can I change the keyboard shortcuts that open control panels in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, customization, i3-wm

I recently installed Regolith Desktop to use alongside Kubuntu Desktop. I really like it, but unfortunately some KDE/Plasma settings are spilling over into Regolith.

One thing that is bothering me is the `meta-s` keyboard shortcut. In i3, it is supposed to turn window stacking on and off. However, for me it brings up the sound control panel. I assume this shortcut to the sound control panel is coming from some Plasma/KDE setting, however I cannot figure out which (so as to disable it).

I have looked in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` as well as Settings > Shortcuts, but I do not see it listed anywhere.

I am having the same issue with `meta-w`, which for me opens the WiFi control panel. I am guessing that both of these settings are in the same place, wherever that is. Can anyone point me towards where these particular shortcuts are set.

Edit: Further information in response to the suggestions.

- My shortcuts settings do not match the KDE documentation linked to, for example I have nothing called "Global shortcuts". Within this area, the `meta-s` and `meta-w` shortcuts do not appear.
  [image: shortcuts]
  [image: custom shortcuts]
- Now that I am back using KDE, I just tried the  `meta-s` and `meta-w` keyboard combinations and they don't work. So maybe it is actually a Regolith issue? I had assumed it was related to KDE as it was a KDE control panel that the shortcut activated.

Solution:
Oh, well silly me. It's just that Regolith has it's own system of keybindings.
https://www.reddit.com/r/regolithlinux/comments/l0kx3f/stacked_and_tabbed_layouts/

Comment: Thanks, but these seem to be referring to the shortcuts panel of System Settings, and the ones I am trying to change are not there (neither in Shortcuts or Custom Shortcuts). I couldn't find anything in my settings called "global shortcuts" though. I thought that is what `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` was.

Comment: Since Ask Ubuntu is a questions-answers site, can you please move the solution from the answer and post it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Regolith or Kubuntu, so I cannot try.
But this *might* help.

To check/modify current *Global Shortcuts*, a few options are available.

1. Use the [Custom Shortcuts System Settings module](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/khotkeys/kcontrol/khotkeys/khotkeys.pdf).
2. Type “shortcuts” in the [app launcher](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-kde-plasma-5/), and then go to “global shortcuts”.
3. Check `~/.config/khotkeysrc` for [further shortcuts](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/add-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal/58654/3).
4. Test which files change when adding new shortcuts. You could use command `find ... -mtime ...`. You could do this within your home dir, or globally.